# Php Yii2 upload base64 image fails with file_put_contents

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2

Am receiving a base64 encoded image from android and i would like to upload it in yii2

SO i have added the following

```
$success = file_put_contents(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/uploads/img.png'
              ,base64_decode($detail));
```

WHere $detail is the base 64 encoded image

When i try uploading am getting an error

```
yii\base\ErrorException: file_put_contents(/uploads/img.png):
  failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

What else do i need to add to make the upload work as most results show the above

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in alias you've used. The `@web` alias is the base **URL** of currently running application which is in your case an empty string. Thanks to that you are trying to save uploaded file as `/uploads/img.png`.

You've probably wanted to use `@webroot` alias instead. It points to the directory that contains index.php file.

You can find more about predefined aliases [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-aliases#predefined-aliases).

Answer (score 2):

uploads folder is in the **web** folder

```
$success = file_put_contents(Yii::getAlias('@web/uploads/img.png'
              ,base64_decode($detail));
```

base path or **root** of the project

```
$success = file_put_contents(Yii::getAlias('@app/uploads/img.png'
              ,base64_decode($detail)); //base path

$success = file_put_contents(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/uploads/img.png'
              ,base64_decode($detail)); //root directory(directory containing the entry script.)
```

**More examples:**
 In the root of the project

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/uploads/img.png';
\yii\helpers\Url::to('@webroot/uploads/img.png');
```

Get a file from a folder in the project root (the code is in another folder):

```
__DIR__.'\..\uploads\img.png'
```